# Program successfully executed with exit code 0 but nothing is printed

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code is getting compiled successfully but no message is being displayed, i.e no print command is being executed.

What's the error in my Python 3.7 code?

```
def isPalindrome(n):
    s=0
    while n!=0 :
        d=n%10
        s+=d
        s*=10
        n/=10
    if n==s :
        return True
    else :
        return False

def main():
    if isPalindrome(252) :
        print('252 is a Palindrome Number')
    else :
        print('252 is not a Palindrome number')
```

Comment: `main` will not execute when you run the program. Add `if __name__ == "__main__": main()` to the bottom of your program.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does if \_\_name\_\_ == "\_\_main\_\_": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Answer (score 1):

main doesn't execute on it's own in Python.

You can put it in:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

or you can just put main() outside entirely, like so...

```
def isPalindrome(n):
    s=0
    while n!=0 :
            d=n%10
            s+=d
            s*=10
            n/=10
    if n==s :
            return True
    else :
            return False

def main():
    if isPalindrome(252) :
            print('252 is a Palindrome Number')
    else :
            print('252 is not a Palindrome number')

main()
```

the former is better if you want to import the function into another program.

But the latter is fine if it's just a stand alone program

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define main here. Below will do for you .

```
def isPalindrome(n):
        s=0
        while n!=0 :
                d=n%10
                s+=d
                s*=10
                n/=10
        if n==s :
                return True
        else :
                return False


if isPalindrome(252) :
        print('252 is a Palindrome Number')
else :
        print('252 is not a Palindrome number')
```